# Recursive function that allocates at the end of the stack

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, ubuntu, recursion

Ok, I'm coming across a strange issue.  I'm implementing an algorithm called the sieve of eratosthenes.  I have a function `primeArray_r` that recursively works through my array I've generated, and then once it comes to the end, it creates a new array on the heap and then starts filling it up as it descends back down through the stack, finally returning the pointer to the the beginning of the array.  If you are wondering why I am incrementing the pointers directly, it's a requirement for the assignment.  I get issues during runtime, but it depends of the environment I am using.
In Windows, it seems to explode without warning, sometimes while repeating the exact same sequence.  In Ubuntu Linux, it's very weird.  It's a little more stable, if it works once, it will work multiple times on that same input, but it fails depending on the input.  For example, my install on bare metal, Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit the program will crash if the upper bound is 5, 9, 13, 17... or any number (N*4)+1, where on my virtual install, Lubuntu 13.10 32-bit, it will crash if the upper bound is 2, 4, 6, 8... or any number N*2.  The error messages are basically the same:

```
Program5.1: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The only difference is the line number, malloc.c.2369 in Lubuntu 13.10 and 2372 in Ubuntu 14.04
It appears to be that I am causing some kind of crash during memory allocation on line 116:
`primeArray = new int[primeCount];`

I wonder if this is an error on my part, or whether I've found some bug exposed when allocation memory at the end of a recursive stack

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int* makeArray(int);
int firstZero (int*);
void circleCross(int*, int*, int);
void circleAll(int*, int*);
int* primeArray(int*, int*, int&, int);
int* primeArray_r(int*, int*, int*, int&, int);

int main(){
    //display a title
    cout << "The Sieve of Eratosthenes" << endl;
    cout << "gives you all the primes you want!" << endl;
    cout << "(in the range you specify...)" << endl;
    //ask the user to specify a range of positive numbers
    char repeat;
    int low;
    int high;
    int size;
    do{
        do{
            low = 0;
            high = 0;
            while (low < 1){
                cout << "Give me the lower bound" << endl;
                cin >> low;
            }
            while (high < 1){
                cout << "Give me the upper bound" << endl;
                cin >> high;
            }
        }while (low > high);
        size = high + 1;
        int* array = makeArray(size);
        int *end = array + size;
        int ix;
        double root = sqrt(high);
        do{
            ix = firstZero(array);
            if (ix <= root)
                circleCross(array, end, ix);
        }while ( ix < root);
        circleAll(array, end);
        array += low;
        cout << "Found all the primes!" << endl;
        int primeCount = 0;
        int* arrayPrime = primeArray(array, end, primeCount, low);
        cout << "Here's your primes!" << endl;
        int *primeEnd = arrayPrime + primeCount;
        while(arrayPrime < primeEnd){
            cout << *arrayPrime << endl;
            ++arrayPrime;
        }
        cout << "Enter 'y' to go or any other character to stop" << endl;
        cin >>  repeat;
    } while(repeat == 'y');

    return 0;
}

int* makeArray( int size){
    int *array;
    array = new int[size];
    int *firstAddress = array;
    *array = -1;
    *(++array) = -1;
    int *end = firstAddress + size;
    while (array < end){*(++array) = 0;}
    return firstAddress;
}

int firstZero ( int* array){
    int *ix;
    for (ix = array; (*ix); ++ix);
    int zero = ix - array;
    return zero;
}

void circleCross( int* array, int *end, int factor){
    array += factor;
    *array = 1;
    array += factor;
    while(array < end){
        *array = -1;
        array += factor;
    }
}

void circleAll( int* array, int *end){
    while (array < end){
        if (*array==0)
            *array=1;
        ++array;
    }
}

int* primeArray( int* array, int *end, int &primeCount, int low){
    primeCount=0;
    int *beginning = array;
    int *primeArray = primeArray_r(array, beginning, end, primeCount, low);
    return primeArray;
}

int* primeArray_r(int * array, int * beginning, int *end, int &primeCount, int low){
    int *primeArray;
    if (array == end){
        primeArray = new int[primeCount];
        primeArray += primeCount;
    }
    else{
        if (*array == 1){
            int position = primeCount; 
            ++primeCount;
            primeArray = primeArray_r((array+1), beginning, end, primeCount, low);
            --primeArray;
            *primeArray = array - beginning + low;
        }
        else{
            primeArray = primeArray_r((array+1), beginning, end, primeCount, low);
        }
    }
    return primeArray;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in your code, because the program halts with an assert which normally means that the user-code is missbehaving and you say that it crashes on different systems.  I also see that you don't free your new'ed array, so you have a memory leak and pointer arithmetic (especially with pointers to allocated memory) is always tricky.  But I don't find the culprit without further investigation, so I'm just giving my thought in a comment.

Comment: I would hand trace this with small values like two and five to confirm the implementation matches expectations.  Then step through the code with your debugger, keeping track that the variables all behave as expected.  There are quite a few things to track through this process.  The behavior indicates base cases for the recursion are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In makeArray(), you are writing a 0 after the array (`while (array < end){*(++array) = 0;}`), which creates undefined behavior.  So this is a very likely reason for your crash, since that also has to do with allocating memory.

Comment: Thad did it, I changed the code so it was post-incrementing rather than pre incrementing and it is working as expected